# Create SQL Server database in Visual Studio for a Winforms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I need in education to do win-forms app, recently I done project on asp.net, there I created without any problem new SQL Server database and send it to SQL Server, and added it to project.

But how can I do this using simple windows forms? Are there any good tutorials? (also I need something like db designer).

On asp.net mvc I use linq...  But couldn't find good tutorial for create, send and attach SQL Server database on winforms.

I do this with .net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Database product is called **SQL Server** (not `mssql`) - and there is no SQL Server **2010** version - you have 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 (Visual Studio 2010 comes with SQL Server **2008 Express**, if that's what you're using)

Comment: What do you mean "create, send and attach"? Creating a database and attaching it can be done via the Management Studio, but what on earth do you mean by "send"?

Comment: You should be able to do it exactly the same way.

Comment: @Arran send)) mean send it to my winforms app... as db service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework Code First to design your db and then call Database.SetInitializer to create the database. Take a look at this article [Understanding Database Initializers in Entity Framework Code First](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)